# Get active object from clsid C#

Tags: c#

I've been looking for a simple way of obtaining an active object (on the ROT) with C#. I found `Marshal.getActiveObject()` but unfortunately this only takes a progid!

My current approach:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class COMHelper {
  [DllImport("oleaut32.dll", PreserveSig=false)]
  static extern void GetActiveObject(
                                        ref Guid   rclsid,
                                            IntPtr pvReserved,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] out Object ppunk
  );
  [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
  static extern int CLSIDFromString(
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]      string lpszProgID,
                                        out Guid   pclsid
  );
  public static object getActiveObject(string sClsid){
    Guid clsid;
    CLSIDFromString(sClsid, out clsid);

    object obj;
    GetActiveObject(ref clsid, IntPtr.Zero, out obj);

    return obj;
  }
}
//...later...
COMHelper.getActiveObject("{a7161d1c-2ac0-4d5f-a56d-4043b5ce69a8}").whatever()
```

This is fine but it's quite chunky. I wondered, is there another built-in mechanism?

Comment: If I search for "c# running object table", I can see some slightly simpler implementations. It's not going to get that much simpler.  Just feel sorry for those of us who had to deal with the stuff back in the pre-.NET days

Comment: @Flydog57 ironically that's what I'm doing in the [VBA world](https://github.com/sancarn/stdVBA/blob/master/src/stdCOM.cls). I'm used to complex implementations but had hoped C# would have been better.